# CSS and HTML doesn't shows properly in iOS and MacOS Safari even Chrome

Tags: html, css, ios, macos, safari

I have the following issue:
I have this under construction state website, https://endertainment.com, it was build with PHP and MySQL from scratch, like any other I did. The issue is when you access the website from Mobile Safari or Safari the website doesn't show all the elements must show. When you access from Android (Any Browser) or Windows or even in Linux the website shows any element well. I already run test in **BrowserStack** and **CrossBrowserTesting**... in both shows the same result; the web didn't show properly. I already remove every flexbox property and use inline-block instead. For example, this other website (https://tuticketazo.com) is under construction state too and use the same structure of https://endertainment.com.
I already made tests changing the server folder the domain points; upload a simple html page from scratch, without PHP ; use without SSL... I think already test everything but in iOS Safari, Mac OS Safari and even in Chrome in MacOS shows the elements but not in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You should set line-height of your heading titles.

```
#MainTitles h1 { line-height: 50px } 

#LangSelect a { line-height: 20px; }
```

But the problem is not inside these 2 rules. I didn't determinate full code of CSS, I just check small fixes for places which I saw broken

Comment: Hi, i already add this two lines to my CSS file, now in iPhone the H1 shows, but no the #LangSelect (language menu) and the <p> below the H1.
Another strange thing, in iPhone with i tap the H1 it disappear!

Comment: Replace this line:
#LangSelect a { line-height: 20px; }

With this:

#LangSelect a {
    line-height: 36px;
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
}

Comment: WOW! it works! But the <p> below the H1 I made the same and still doesn't shows

Comment: Replace:

#MainTitles h1 {
    margin: 30px auto;
}

with:

#MainTitles h1 {
    margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
}

And 
#MainTitles p {
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
}

With:
#MainTitles p {
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
}

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and resolve the Issue.
OS X have a rendering issue with some fonts.
I start my research searching a common pattern, I has this issue with 3 websites:

1. Adjusting the line-height didn't work properly.
2. Change the ul from inline-block to flexbox, didn't work
3. The issue is present in any browser in Mac OS (I test Chrome,
   Firefox and Safari)

Continue researching an I found some documentation about the issue.
I found this [article](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=480196)
OS X type rendering - text baseline is shifted upwards, effectively no-longer centered vertically within the line-height
I test in the 3 different websites have the issue and VOILA!
Everything works fine now.
I used in the 3 websites the same fonts (the common pattern):

1. Gotham Book
2. Gotham Black

I can confirm this two fonts evoke the rendering issue in Mac Os.
The problem is solved right now.